# Python pip using proxy only works with one specific Python version, not with another installed on the same VM

Tags: python, pip, proxy, redhat

I would like to install Python packages on a specific Python version (3.9), previously installed on a RedHat VM.
I already tries to install them on previous versions (3.6) using proxy, but when I try the very same procedure with the desired version it fails.

I defined my proxy variables ($HTTPS_PROXY, $HTTP_PROXY) in a dedicated file and set them (`source .proxy_file`).

Trying to install any package on Python 3.6 works successfully:

```
python3 -m pip install --proxy $http_proxy datetime
```

Trying with Python 3.9, it gives the following error, specifying **ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 400 Bad Request**':

```
python3.9 -m pip install --proxy $http_proxy datetime

WARNING: Running pip install with root privileges is generally not a good idea. Try `python3.9 -m pip install --user` instead.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 400 Bad Request'))': /simple/datetime/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 400 Bad Request'))': /simple/datetime/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 400 Bad Request'))': /simple/datetime/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 400 Bad Request'))': /simple/datetime/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 400 Bad Request'))': /simple/datetime/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement datetime (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for datetime
```